# ElasticSearch query to only 8 indices is already filling the search.queue (capacity 1000)

Tags: elasticsearch

We are running a single ES node with version 2.3.1.

There is a query which returns basically a number of unique users (unique values of a user ID field) in daily buckets, for the last week (168 hours). This query affects 8 indices.

In the past, such a query ran quickly. It got slower over time, but now we are getting rejections and can't figure out why. We found that the `search.queue` immediately fills up when we run this query - it goes to around 350, then 640, then 1000, and the rejections are coming in (these steps happen within a few seconds while the query is running).

I don't understand how this is possible, because it should affect only 8 indices with 2 shards each, and it worked nicely in the past.

The query is:

```
GET /abcdefg-2016.09.05%2Cabcdefg-2016.09.06%2Cabcdefg-2016.09.07%2Cabcdefg-2016.09.08%2Cabcdefg-2016.09.09%2Cabcdefg-2016.09.10%2Cabcdefg-2016.09.11%2Cabcdefg-2016.09.12/abcdefg/_search
{
  "sort": {},
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "fields": [
    "*",
    "_source",
    "_field_names"
  ],
  "fielddata_fields": [
    "@timestamp"
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": 1473073782735,
                  "lte": 1473678582735
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "demo"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [],
          "should": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "date_histogram": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "1d",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": 1473073782735,
          "max": 1473678582735
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_users_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "usedUID"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "unique_users_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "usedUID"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running `curl localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool?v` when the query got stuck shows:

```
host      ip        bulk.active bulk.queue bulk.rejected index.active index.queue index.rejected search.active search.queue search.rejected
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1           0          0             0            0           0              0             4         1000          132228
```

It will stay this way for several minutes, and then the queue will go back to zero.

What can be the problem?

**EDIT:** Adding profile:true gives this output: http://pastebin.com/s4jpw36d

**EDIT2:** What is weirdest is that in the profile output I see that ES sends tons of these weird queries to Lucene:

```
  {
    "query_type": "BooleanQuery",
    "lucene": "@timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xD @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xE @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xF @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xG @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xH @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xI @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xJ @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xK @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xL @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xM @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xN @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xO @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xP @timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xQ",
    "time": "61.40814100ms",
    "breakdown": {
      "score": 0,
      "create_weight": 357521,
      "next_doc": 40988029,
      "match": 0,
      "build_scorer": 2733654,
      "advance": 0
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "query_type": "TermQuery",
        "lucene": "@timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xD",
        "time": "0.1429700000ms",
        "breakdown": {
          "score": 0,
          "create_weight": 21940,
          "next_doc": 99164,
          "match": 0,
          "build_scorer": 21866,
          "advance": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "query_type": "TermQuery",
        "lucene": "@timestamp:0 \u0000\u0000\n[xE",
        "time": "0.5797620000ms",
        "breakdown": {
          "score": 0,
          "create_weight": 64810,
          "next_doc": 501767,
          "match": 0,
          "build_scorer": 13185,
          "advance": 0
        }
      }, 
      ...
    ]
  }
```

**EDIT3:** Okay, this appears to be intentional: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es-rewriting-range-to-timestamp-to-booleanquery-termquery-why/56363 - However it doesn't make sense to me that it would now make the queries unusable, clogging the otherwise-empty queue...

Comment: `"unique_users_count": {
      "value": 332725
    }` uhhh, most things kinda crash with that amount of items trying to load into memory... it's twenty short of three fiddy thousand...

Comment: Can you provide the log file of the node for today? (assuming your tests were performed today)

Answer (score 1):

Re:  **EDIT3.**  I have a hunch that there's a bug in that optimization ("rewriting range...")

The switching code looks at the TermsEnum  [MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper.java:147](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper.java#L147) when deciding whether to rewrite the range query as a boolean.  If `TermsEnum.next()` returns `null` (which I believe it will, when there is no term vector for the field), then the `collectTerms` method returns `true` (and the query is rewritten as a boolean query... even without a term vector!)

You're doing something a little non-standard by pulling your `@timestamp` from the field cache in your query here:

```
  "fielddata_fields": [
    "@timestamp"
  ],
```

The fact that you're using the fielddata workaround indicates that you may not be storing term information with your timestamp field (why would you anyway?!) which the range-optimization expects.  But then you're passing a reference to a field reconstructed at query-time from the field-cache (which is not likely to be something there's preexisting test-coverage for).

---

As a workaround, and general tuning improvement, I'd make sure you haven't disabled [docvalues](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_deep_dive_on_doc_values.html) for your timestamp field (in your index mappings), then just reference your timestamp field directly in your aggregations (`timestamp` vs `@timestamp`).  If you've explicitly disabled docvalues for `timestamp` in your mapping, then you'll have to reindex old data, or just wait until your indexing changes have rolled forward enough for your query to succeed (all clean indices).

*Docvalues* are a best-practice for aggregations these days.  They are enabled by default in ES 2.0+ for field types that support them, and they spare you many performance issues w.r.t. aggregations (and potentially also spare you any unexpected "optimization" headaches!)

Here's a good post which talks about scale issues introduced by the field-cache and why you should use docvalues:  https://www.elastic.co/blog/support-in-the-wild-my-biggest-elasticsearch-problem-at-scale